# Reminder API in iOS 6.0

Tags: ios, iphone, storekit

Strange bug in iOS 6.0 sdk. Apple promised to deliver full reminder support via api, to allow thirdparty applications to read and write reminders on behalf of user. There is new methods in SDK to init storekit for use with reminders.

But seems like main method to make it possible - just not present. Both GM version of XCode 4.5 and simulator/ios-6 upgraded device shows that `EKEventStore:initWithAccessToEntityTypes` is not present in SDK and attempt to call it on device/simulator crashing application with

```
Error invoking method 'EKRemsIsGranted' on 'CEKtils' because 
-[EKEventStore initWithAccessToEntityTypes:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x13a59140
```

Interesting that this method is also mentioned and described in [MacOs 10.8](https://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)
but in iOS sdk it is [mentioned but NOT described](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/EventKit/Reference/EKEventStoreClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)

Seems like apple devs forgot to "enable" it on iOS. is it possible at all or I missing something?

Comment: Please do not report bugs to StackOverflow; there's nothing StackOverflow can do.  Instead, please log any bugs with Apple.

Comment: It looks like what you're saying is: a method that is not documented in iOS is not there. Isn't that what you'd expect?

Comment: question should be asked in apple devs forum. Concerning initWithAccessToEntityTypes they are definitely messed up docs

Answer (score 0):

There's a description of the event (and some other useful information) [here.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/ReadingAndWritingEvents.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004775-SW3) You might also double-check that your UIEventKit framework is properly linked and up to date.